# Credit and Debit Cards Stopped Working in Spain

Tags: credit-card, travel, spain

I'm currently travelling in Europe with a VISA debit card for a Charles Schwab Checking Account as well as an American Express Bonvoy credit card. Both cards target travellers and don't usually require travel notices. I had been using both cards successfully earlier in my trip, as well as in Madrid - but when I arrived in the Murcia region of Spain, I discovered I couldn't use either card anywhere - no merchants, no ATMs. My first thought that was that I needed to give a travel notice after all, but when I called to do so, both Charles Schwab and American Express told me they had no records of any declined transactions - none of the purchases I'd been trying to make had even reached the card providers.

- **It's a not a travel notice problem** - the card companies weren't declining the charges, and both cards now have active travel notices.
- **The cards are both in good standing.** I have used both to make online purchases since this problem started.
- **The merchants accept both kinds of cards**. I only tried the AmEx at merchants who advertised supporting AmEx, and the VISA didn't work anywhere either, or any ATMs.
- **I am entering my ATM pin correctly**. I'm sure I know what it is because it's the same pin I use everywhere, and the number pad layouts are different between ATMs here so I have to be very deliberate about entering it. Also, Schwab says they have no records of incorrect PIN attempts.
- **The cards are not physically damaged** because entering the card numbers directly at self-service checkouts didn't work, nor did using Google Pay NFC backed by those cards.

Again, neither Schwab nor AmEx seem to have any record of any of these attempted transactions.

No banking official in Spain, or customer service representative for either company, seems to have any idea what the problem might be or how I can fix it. I am staying with a friend in Murcia and can send him money via PayPal to give me back in cash, but soon I'll be solo, and I don't want to do so until I'm sure I'll be able to make purchases or, at least, withdraw cash on my own. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: What exact message are you (or the merchant operating the POS terminal) receiving when you try a transaction?

Comment: @dwizum The messages differ for different merchants, and it's hard for me to tell exactly because I don't speak Spanish. The ATMs, which have English interfaces, will say something like "Transaction not completed". The self-service terminal at McDonald's said "Card Invalid" for the AmEx, both when swiped and when charged via Google Pay. I didn't see anything like specific codes or otherwise technical information on the terminals when I used them.

Comment: This is tough to troubleshoot remotely, especially without seeing the return codes. It may be the case that the transaction is getting stopped by the network(s) or merchant's bank(s) but having two cards on different networks blocked at different merchants makes that seem unlikely. It's also hard to know why the issuing banks can't help you, since even if the transaction is stopped before it gets to them, they should be able to check with another entity (the network or merchant's bank) to help troubleshoot for you. When you send your friend money via paypal, are you using these cards to fund?

Comment: PayPal was actually withdrawing directly from the checking account for which the Schwab is the debit card, but not via the debit card itself. My friend I'm staying with speaks Spanish, and I may be able to persuade him to accompany me to a merchant and work with them to troubleshoot. What sorts of things should I ask the merchant or look for on the terminal?

Comment: AmEx is often not accepted, so I would focus on debugging the Visa card which should be almost universally accepted.

Comment: I had something similar a year ago or so. In my case it was the chip on the card that got damaged. Online transactions worked, swiping the card worked, but transactions like with an ATM where the chip is read didn't work and gave similar errors. My bank sent me a new card and all was fine.

Comment: Did you transport your credit cards near magnets? near your cellphone?

Comment: @Aganju OP reported that the cards worked in Madrid but Murcia is a much smaller city.